# Simple drop-down calendar + date picker in Python

Tags: tkinter, datepicker, calendar, python-3.6, dropdown

Trying to create a simple drop-down calendar with a date picker in Python such that a field drops down to show a calendar where after a date is selected is captured - I have not yet come across a clean, simple and short code for Python 3.6.1. Therefore, need help with creating a simple drop down date picker in Python.

EDIT : I was not able to access Calendar, DateEntry widgets from the package tkcalendar earlier and therefore created a class to render the same using the answer below.

[image]

Comment: May you get something from this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580725-tkinter-datepicker-like-the-jquery-ui-datepicker/

Comment: You could take a look at the `DateEntry` widget in https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What do you need help with?

Comment: @BryanOakley : Need help with creating a simple drop down date picker in Python - a piece of code/useful link would be of great help. (edited the question as well)

Comment: @MuhammadNoman : Thanks! Can you add your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: @GarimaTiwari Sure. I have added this as an answer now. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadNoman Your answer seems to have disappeared?

Comment: Oh. Just checked. I was deleted by someone else. Irony is that I am not able to undelete

Comment: It requires 5 upvotes to undelete it.

Answer (score 6):

first pip install tkcalendar then

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkcalendar import DateEntry
root = tk.Tk()
cal = DateEntry(root, width=12, year=2019, month=6, day=22, 
background='darkblue', foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just adding that the import tkinter as tk needs to be included as well for the above code to work.

Comment: There's no Tk() class in tkcalendar....  what gives?

Comment: @MrDysprosium juste add *import tkinter as tk*

Comment: how to store the picked date in a variable from this?

Comment: @Wizytor check documentation https://pypi.org/project/tkcalendar/#widget-methods-1,  you are looking for get_date()

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
pip install panel
```

Second:

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension()

pn.widgets.DatePicker(name='Set Starting Date')
```